# Why isn't my DSLR's viewfinder showing focus correctly after removing it for cleaning?

Tags: dslr, troubleshooting, repair, cleaning, viewfinder

I've tried to clean focusing screen of my Nikon D750 by removing it out of the body and placed it back after cleaning. From then on, the focusing is acting weird. When I look through the viewfinder, in-focus subjects are blurry and out of focus subjects are clear. When I click a pic, I can see that the out of focus subjects through viewfinder are actually in focus in the picture. Why's this happening?

Comment: If you look through th OVF, is the text like ISO or shutterspeed displayed clearly?

Comment: Yes. Everything is clear except the subject on which focus is locked on.

Comment: Yes. Tried to focus with several focusing modes and different focus point positions too.

Comment: You may have misaligned the focusing screen, knocked the mirror out of place, or changed the diopter setting.

Comment: Mirror is perfectly in place. Diopter is in usual setting. I think the issue might be with focusing screen. Does wiping it with a microfiber cloth remove some sort of coating on it?

Comment: Can it be inserted upside down or is it keyed to prevent this?

Comment: The focusing screen and mirror surface are two of the most delicate parts of an SLR/DSLR! They're much more fragile than the surface of the filter stack in front of the sensor. Touching them should almost always be avoided. Damage to them can affect metering (because the light meter for such cameras is in the optical path past the mirror and focusing screen) if the reflectance of the mirror or the transmittance of the focusing screen is affected. Yes, dust in the viewfinder's optical path can be distracting, but it does not affect recorded images. Clean them at your own risk!

Comment: I'm planning to send it to Nikon Service center. Any idea on how much would they charge for replacing focusing screen?

Answer (score 13):

Solved. I accidentally placed the focusing screen by flipping it on other side which made in focus objects blurry. I corrected it and it's back to normal now.